# Grouping images to display in LightBox

Tags: javascript, asp.net, lightbox2

I have an ASP.Net web page and have created a custom control that's soul purpose is to be a list "item" displayed in the main page's panel (asp:Panel), here is that list control:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="cListItem.ascx.cs"       Inherits="CatPro.Presentation.UserControls.CatalyticItem" %>
<script src="../Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="../Scripts/lightbox-2.6.min.js"></script>
<link href="../Css/lightbox.css" rel="stylesheet" />

</style>
<table class="MainFrame" border="1" runat="server">
  <tr>
    <td runat="server">
  <table class="MainFrame">

    <tr>
      <td class="CatImageColumn" rowspan="5">            
        <asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server" 
              RepeatColumns="5" 
              RepeatDirection="Horizontal" 
              RepeatLayout="Flow">
          <ItemTemplate>
            <a id="ImageLink"  href='<%# Eval((string)Container.DataItem) %>' data-lightbox="image-1">
               <img id="Img1" src="<%# (string)Container.DataItem %>" width="150" height="150">
             </a>
          </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:DataList>                  
      </td>
      <td class="LinkHeader" colspan="5">
        <asp:LinkButton ID="hyperlinkDescription" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="X-Large">Item Description Link</asp:LinkButton>
      </td>
      <td class="LinkHeader">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="FirstRowLabel">
        <asp:Label ID="lblYear" runat="server" Text="Year"></asp:Label>
      </td>
      <td class="FirstRowText">
        <asp:Label ID="txtYear" runat="server"></asp:Label>
      </td>
      <td class="SecondRowLabel">
        <asp:Label ID="lblRasCategory" runat="server" Text="RAS Category:"></asp:Label>
      </td>
      <td class="SecondRowText">
        <asp:Label ID="txtRASCategory" runat="server"></asp:Label>
      </td>
      <td class="ThirdRowLabel">
        <asp:Label ID="lblValue89" runat="server" Text="Value:" ForeColor="Green"></asp:Label>
      </td>
      <td class="ThirdRowText">
        <asp:Label ID="txtValue89" runat="server" ForeColor="Green">$0</asp:Label>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="FirstRowLabel">
        <asp:Label ID="lblMake" runat="server" Text="Make:"></asp:Label>
      </td>
      <td class="FirstRowText">
        <asp:Label ID="txtMake" runat="server"></asp:Label>
      </td>
      <td class="SecondRowLabel">
        <asp:Label ID="lblPMCategory" runat="server" Text="PowerMount Category:"></asp:Label>
      </td>
      <td class="SecondRowText">
        <asp:Label ID="txtPMCategory" runat="server"></asp:Label>
      </td>
      <td class="ThirdRowLabel">
        <asp:Label ID="lblValue100" runat="server" Text="Value:" ForeColor="Green"></asp:Label>
      </td>
      <td class="ThirdRowText">
        <asp:Label ID="txtValue100" runat="server" ForeColor="Green">$0</asp:Label>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="FirstRowLabel">
        <asp:Label ID="lblModel" runat="server" Text="Model:"></asp:Label>
      </td>
      <td class="FirstRowText">
        <asp:Label ID="txtModel" runat="server"></asp:Label>
      </td>
      <td class="SecondRowLabel">
        <asp:Label ID="lblOENumber" runat="server" Text="OE Number:"></asp:Label>
      </td>
      <td class="SecondRowText">
        <asp:Label ID="txtOENumber" runat="server"></asp:Label>
      </td>
      <td class="ThirdRowLabel"></td>
      <td class="ThirdRowText"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="FirstRowLabel">
        <asp:Label ID="lblSubModel" runat="server" Text="Sub Model:"></asp:Label>
      </td>
      <td class="FirstRowText">
        <asp:Label ID="txtSubModel" runat="server"></asp:Label>
      </td>
      <td class="SecondRowLabel">
        &nbsp;</td>
      <td class="SecondRowText">
        &nbsp;</td>
      <td class="ThirdRowLabel">&nbsp;</td>
      <td class="ThirdRowText">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</td>
```

For every record returned from a database call, one of these controls is added to the main page's Panel control. Each item may have more than 1 image, so i store them in a asp:DataList in the code behind:

```
  string[] images = listCImages.Select(c => c.ImagePath).ToArray();
  DataList1.DataSource = images;
  DataList1.DataBind();
```

Ideally, i would like to display the first image in the data set on the control, then when clicked have the LightBox control display the related image collection (by clicking through the set in the LightBox window).

This is the section that uses the LightBox control i'm having issues setting up

```
<asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server" 
              RepeatColumns="5" 
              RepeatDirection="Horizontal" 
              RepeatLayout="Flow">
          <ItemTemplate>
            <a id="ImageLink"  href='<%# Eval((string)Container.DataItem) %>' data-lightbox="image-1">
               <img id="Img1" src="<%# (string)Container.DataItem %>" width="150" height="150">
             </a>
          </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:DataList>
```

I can load and display a single image with no issue, but my attempts to perform the above mentioned has not been so simple. Is this the right approach? What alterations should i make to get the desired outcome?

Answer (score 0):

I've temporarily solved this by doing somewhat of a hack (a sloppy method in my opinion)...

I first dynamically created my display image:

```
  //Create a HyperLink control
  HyperLink linkWrapper = new HyperLink();
  linkWrapper.ID = catId.ToString();

  //assign a lightbox attribute
  linkWrapper.Attributes.Add("rel", string.Format("lightbox[{0}]", catId.ToString()));
  linkWrapper.Attributes.Add("title", string.Format("Image(s) for  {0}", catId.ToString()));

  //The path to my local image
  linkWrapper.NavigateUrl = imagePath;

  //next, create a display image
  Image mainImage = new Image();
  mainImage.Height = 128;
  mainImage.Width = 128;
  mainImage.ID = "img_" + catId.ToString();
  mainImage.ImageUrl = imagePath;

  //wrap the link around the image
  linkWrapper.Controls.Add(mainImage);

  //dynamically add display control to td cell
  CatImages.Controls.Add(linkWrapper);
```

Then, if there were any other associated images, i added them like:

```
foreach (catImage cat in listCatImages) //custom generic list iteration
{
  //create a HyperLink control
  HyperLink hl = new HyperLink();
  hl.Attributes.Add("rel", string.Format("lightbox[{0}]", catalyticConverterId.ToString()));
  hl.Attributes.Add("title", "My Cats");
  hl.NavigateUrl = cat.ImagePath;

  //add just the link to the td cell
  CatImages.Controls.Add(hl);
}
```

Now, when i click on the "Display Image", LightBox picks up the image group and allows me to navigate through them (and the links are not visible).